# async not waiting for await in callback to finish

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

Im still a rookie with async and awaits, but this is what Im working with.

```
    async function _getImageURLs(folder) {
         if (!id) return;

         foo.AWSS3Helper.GetImageUrls(so, function (imageUrls) {
             return await imageUrls;
         });
    }
```

The fuction **_getImageURLs()** is still returning without waiting for the AWSS3Helper.GetImageUrls finishes. Im guessing it has something to do with being inside a callback function. Does the callback need to be async as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use await on the function not on the return statement

```js
  async function _getImageURLs(folder) {
         if (!id) return;

         foo.AWSS3Helper.GetImageUrls(so, await function (imageUrls) {
             return  imageUrls;
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with observables. Something like this...

```
   function _getImageURLs(folder) {
             if (!id) return;

             const imageUrlObservable = of(foo.AWSS3Helper
                  .GetImageUrls(so, function (imageUrls) {
                     return imageUrls;
                   })
             );

             imageUrlObservable.subscribe({
                 next(imageUrL) { console.log(imageUrL) },
                 complete() { console.log('Finished sequence'); }
             });


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see there are no promises here, you have a callback based mechanism on the api so using `async/await` seems pointless

you should pass a callback to the method and invoking it as soon as you have the result available

```
function _getImageURLs(folder, callback) {
     if (!id) callback();

     foo.AWSS3Helper.GetImageUrls(so, function (imageUrls) {
         callback(imageUrls);
     });
}

_getImageURLs("somefolder", function(result) {
   console.log(result);
   // do whatever you want here with the result
 };
```